# A confusion of 2d array initalization with c++

Tags: c++, arrays

An initialization code like

```
int len=s.length();    //s is an input string

int dp[len][len]={0};  //pre-set whole 2d array with zero
```

This initialization cannot be compiled in my local ubuntu (14.04) with g++ v4.8.1.(my compiling option is "-g -std=gnu++11 -gstabs+"):

```
error: variable-sized object ‘dp’ may not be initialized
int dp[len][len]={0};
                   ^
```

However, it can be accepted by online judge of leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/).

So I feel confused, which one is correct..? Or both?

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: Use std::vector Dave.

Comment: I wrote std::array initially and changed it to vector about 2 seconds after I realised my error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks!

Comment: @Robinson Yes I agree.

Comment: Some are suggesting using vector of vectors. Depending on your application it may be more effective to use a 1-D vector, and compute the offsets as you need them.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's true, sometime I will set up a 1-d vector and calculate offset with (x,y) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int dp[len][len]={0};
```

Is a variable length array and it is not standard in C++.  Some compiler support them as an extension and this is why they can work on some machines but not others.  If you need an "Array" that you will not know the size of until run-time I would suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
auto dp = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(len, std::vector<int>(len, 0));
                                        ^^^ # of rows         ^^^  ^value of all cells
                                                        # of cols
```

You could also use a 1 dimensional vector use an offset to get the correct cell.

```
auto dp = std::vector<int>(len * len, 0);
dp[row_number * len + col_number] = some_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vector` instead.

```
auto one_row = std::vector<int>         (len , 0);
auto dp      = std::vector<vector<int>> (len , one_row );
```

Comment: Thanks~. I agree with you, just confused with the diffrent behaviors.

Comment: This doesn't compile - class templates must have the template parameters specified , they can't be deduced from constructor arguments

Comment: Why are you creating a 1d vector and then using that to create the 2d vector?  You could be leaving a large object in the heap if `len` is large.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, thanks Matt. Changed now to include the types

Comment: @NathanOliver, if `len` is large, say `1000`, then this will mean 1,001,000 `int` instead of 1,000,000. So it's not an issue. 0.1% extra. Priority is to have easy-to-read code